# How can i get python to print a number not "nan"

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, equation

So I am trying to make a program that will calculate a very advanced equation with some input the user must provide, although when I print the variables it just shows as `nan`

The code:

```
import os
import math

os.system("CLS")

m = float(input("Mass (in kg): "))
r = float(input("Radius (in m): "))
A = math.pi*r**2
k = 0.5*1.22*0.75*A
I = float(input("Impulse of engine (in seconds): "))
T = float(input("Thrust of engine (in Kn): ")*1000)
t = I/T
g = 9.82
GravForce = m*g
q = math.sqrt((T-m*g)/k)
x = 2*k*q/m
p = 1.22

v = q*(1-math.exp(-x*t))/(1+math.exp(-x*t))
yb = (-m/(2*k))*math.log((T-m*g-k*v**2)/(T-m*g))
yc = (+m/(2*k))*math.log((m*g+k*v**2)/(m*g))

print("Velocity at burnout =",v)
print("Boost Phase Distance =",yb)
print("Coast Phase Distance =",yc)
print("Total Altitude =",yb+yc)
```

Thank you for the help, I fixed it by instead of having the T input as input then *1000 I removed that and made the input in newton instead of kilonewton.

Comment: sample inputs where you got `nan`?

Comment: Grab a pad of paper, a pencil and a calculator. Work through your calculation to find out where it's going wrong and producing `nan` as a result. Or use a debugger to step through the code for the same reason.

Comment: As a general rule, don't try to fold input directly into your calculations. `inp = input("...")`, then `T = float(inp) * 1000`. This will help you avoid a lot of errors, and keep your code more readable.

Comment: `T` is `inf` and using `T` calculates are all `inf`, so `v`, `yb` and `yc` are `NaN`.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is the following line of code

```
T = float(input("Thrust of engine (in Kn): ")*1000)
```

change it to

```
T = float(input("Thrust of engine (in Kn): ")) *1000
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is `T` evaluates to`inf` because it tried to convert the string to float type.

> `input("Thrust of engine (in Kn): ")*1000)` is 1,000 times repeated input string and it's try casting to float type.
>   str type can't cast to float type, so `math` evaluates it as `inf`.
>   `math` returns `nan` when it calculate involving `inf`.

```py
import os
import math

os.system("CLS")

m = float(input("Mass (in kg): "))
r = float(input("Radius (in m): "))
A = math.pi*r**2
k = 0.5*1.22*0.75*A
I = float(input("Impulse of engine (in seconds): "))
T = float(input("Thrust of engine (in Kn): "))*1000
t = I/T
g = 9.82
GravForce = m*g
q = math.sqrt((T-m*g)/k)
x = 2*k*q/m
p = 1.22

v = q*(1-math.exp(-x*t))/(1+math.exp(-x*t))
yb = (-m/(2*k))*math.log((T-m*g-k*v**2)/(T-m*g))
yc = (+m/(2*k))*math.log((m*g+k*v**2)/(m*g))

print("Velocity at burnout =",v)
print("Boost Phase Distance =",yb)
print("Coast Phase Distance =",yc)
print("Total Altitude =",yb+yc)
```

Comment: The meaning of the first line of  your answer is not clear (though I think I know what you mean). Please clarify so everyone can understand it.

Comment: Sounds good. I should keep in mind easy-to-understand expressions.